# How do I find the page ids of the current user using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a web form where I ask users to pass me a link about their own facebook page which is not necessarily their own page, but could instead be a separate page for a business or the like.

So far I have implemented a Facebook Login and after the login I use the gained access token to query `/v2.2/me` to gain knowledge of the user id. While it is possible to derive a link to the users personal page that might be the wrong one!

Google solves this quite well by allowing the user to choose which account to use after logging in but before returning an authorization code. Since Facebook does not seem to do that (or can I somehow trigger that behaviour?) I'd like to retrieve a list of all pages managed by the current user and then show a selection page myself. But **how do I get a list of all pages managed by the current user?**.

I thought that /me/accounts might be the right thing. I created an empty test page on my facebook page (for an "artist") but /me/accounts always returns an empty array.

It looks like there are many applications that need a page id out there (like wordpress plugins) where people have to manually supply a page id and thus there are tons of articles, blogs and even SO questions that explain how to derive the page id from an URL, by digging in some settings in Facebook or even Firebug which makes it frustratingly complicated to google for the problem.

I could theoretically tell people to just input their page id and add one of the previously mentioned blog articles, but I think that would not only be unelegant but also flood my with support requests of people who did not manage to find their page id and will also cause people to enter invalid page ids or ids of pages that they don't belong, so I'd appreciate a solution using the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way via the API to find page IDs belonging to the current user is `/me/accounts`. If you were able to retrieve user page accounts without `manage_pages` permission it would be a privacy violation.

Ensure that you granted manage_pages when [logging in](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#adding)

> A user access token with manage_pages is required, and will only allow the retrieval for that specific person.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/accounts

It is up to you to explain to your users why you are using `manage_pages` permission.

If you aren't comfortable with this, then you are out of luck.

The only other way is to have the user go to the URL of the Facebook page and submit it to you, then that's extra overhead for you to verify.

Pages have the following formats

- facebook.com/username
- facebook.com/id
- facebook.com/pages/pagename/id

Once you cover all those bases extract either the username or id and execute a Graph API call

`graph.facebook.com/username` or `graph.facebook.com/id`

Comment: Indeed. (for whatever reason they return an empty list rather than a helpful error message). However that permission would require a facebook review (which will probably cause a major headache as my application is an internal application for which I can't easily give Facebook access to for a review) and also it looks suspicious to users if I ask for permission to manage their pages when all I want is a one-time read-only list of their pages.

Comment: @yankee no. If you are the only one using the permission you don't need to submit it for a review.

Comment: How do you mean the "only one"? I certainly don't want to be the only one capable of telling myself my own page ids. Actually it is the whole purpose of my webpage that other people can tell me about their pages...

Comment: If you want other people to use manage_pages you need to go through review if you don't and it's only you then no. This is the explanation to empty data for /me/accounts

Comment: Seeing that `manage_pages` is a powerful thing (it allows you to make a lot of settings for a page and “act as” the page), I doubt that people will be willing to grant it to your app only so that it can “know” about their pages. Having them input the URL to their pages would be the proper thing to do here instead.